# H2, Spring boot-JPA: Issue with retrieving entity with OffsetTime field

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have a small Spring Boot application (spring-data-jpa) with H2 database (version 1.4.200). I have Shift object, representing a recurring interval in time:

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Shift {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "start_time", columnDefinition = "TIME WITH TIME ZONE")
    private OffsetTime startTime;
    @Column(name = "end_time", columnDefinition = "TIME WITH TIME ZONE")
    private OffsetTime endTime;

    public Shift (OffsetTime startTime, OffsetTime endTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Controller {

    private final ShiftRepository shiftRepository;
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public Shift index() {
        return shiftRepository.getById(1L);
    }

}
```

```
public interface ShiftRepository extends JpaRepository<Shift, Long> {
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class LoadDatabase {
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initUserTable(ShiftRepository repository) {
        return args -> repository
                .save(
                        new Shift(OffsetTime.parse("10:15:30+00:00"), OffsetTime.parse("11:25:30+00:00")));
    }}
```

Retrieving it leads to:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke ""org.h2.engine.CastDataProvider.currentTimestamp()"" because ""<parameter1>"" is null" [50000-200]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:347) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.toSQLException(DbException.java:319) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
> at org.h2.message.TraceObject.logAndConvert(TraceObject.java:366) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
> at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getTime(JdbcResultSet.java:480) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getTime(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
> at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimeTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimeTypeDescriptor.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
> at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
> at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
> at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
> at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
> at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3130) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
> at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
> ... 73 common frames omitted

In debugger I see that indeed there is no timezone set:
[image]

My application.properties which could be relevant:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

Relevant lines from pom.xml:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Do I need to use some custom converter for TIME WITH TIME ZONE database type and OffsetTime Java type?

It works without any exception when I change type to:

```
    @Column(name = "start_time", columnDefinition = "TIME")
    private OffsetTime startTime;
    @Column(name = "end_time", columnDefinition = "TIME")
    private OffsetTime endTime;
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example and this works for me. What versions of Spring Boot and H2 are you using?

Comment: H2: 1.4.200, Spring: 2.3.11.RELEASE.

Comment: Works for me with these versions as well. Can you provide a minimal reproduciable example?

Comment: Changed version to Spring boot 2.5.2. This is minimal code needed to reproduce it.

Comment: Did it work with 2.5.2?

Comment: No, still the same problem. All code is included in the original question. Windows 10, Java 15. Runned with Intellij Idea Ultimate.

Comment: There is a minor bug in JDBC driver of H2 1.4.200: it can't return `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` values with `ResultSet.getTime(column)`. Actually it's a legacy method for `TIME` / `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE` values, **it shouldn't be used** for `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` at all, its result doesn't include time zone offset and has other problems.

The proper methods for this data type are `ResultSet.getObject(column, OffsetTime.class)`, `ResultSet.getObject(column)` etc., but Hibernate due to its own problems with datetime data types uses the wrong method.

Comment: Now I can reproduce the problem. This is very strange! If I run a test with DataJpaTest it works. but when I use SpringBootTest I get the error. Now I try to figure out what's different from these two database setups

Answer (score 2):

Evgenij Ryazanov's comment above was quite helpful. I was having the same problem and was able to fix it by downgrading the version of H2, so I am elevating it here to an answer.

In your `pom.xml`, update to:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <!-- There is a bug with 1.4.200 and retrieving dates back from the DB -->
        <version>1.4.199</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring Boot changed from 1.4.199 [in version 2.1.10](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18593). Spring Boot 2.7 uses the new 2.x version of H2. Presumably that would also be a fix, but I have not tried that out.

Comment: Thank you!  We upgraded to Spring Boot 2.7 and some unit tests all of a sudden started having errors saving LocalDate into H2.  Turns out the new version of H2 always uses the operating system's timezone rather than respecting the timezone set programmatically or through properties